# Objective c AFNetworking rejected on apple because of UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, app-store, app-store-connect, afnetworking

Objective c AFNetworking rejected on apple because of UIWebView. Tried all suggestion. Can't upgrade the library due to it's old app. Latest version can install for AFNetworking is like 3.2.1 something like that.

Has anyone had a remedy and is working?

Comment: Hi Dan , Appstore no longer accepts anything UIWebView . They have completely deprecated it and. no longer supports. ,  you will have to switch to WKWebView instead. Refer to this https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b

Comment: HI Anjula. Yeah. But my problem is AFNetworking removed that UIWebView in their version 4.0. My problem is I can't upgrade to that version because some dependencies will not work as the app is old. I wanted to migrate to swift but client not yet ready.

Answer (score 1):

> If you integrate AFNetworking with Cocoapods and you don't need
> AFNetworking/UIKit subspec, you could define your podfile like this:
> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0', :subspecs => ['Reachability',
> 'Serialization', 'Security', 'NSURLSession', 'NSURLConnection'] Define
> your version number properly and depends on your dependences you could
> remove NSURLConnection.

This is the only option you have given that you do not want to upgrade and im hoping you dont want to use the UIWebView either.

Refer to this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4428

Comment: I had also tried that one but it throws some error/missing dependencies.